# Как состыковать div-блоки?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

Есть два блока 'container'

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 </div>
</div>
```

Во внутри одного из блоков есть блок 'block'. Этот блок я сделал перетаскиваимым (dragable). Как сдетать так чтобы при перетаскивании этого блока из одного в другой блок, он начинал ставать прямо по центру при условии что до цетра осталось некое количество измеряемых единиц?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop-objects